# SEEK_END with WHENCE on binary stream

Tags: c, binary, standards, fseek

I'm confused by this statement, from [C Programming: A Modern Approach, 2nd Edition](http://knking.com/books/c2/index.html) on Page 446,

> For binary streams, `fseek` isn't required to support calls in which whence is `SEEK_END`

Why is that? That seems like weird stipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Looking it up [in the spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf), it says

> Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, has undefined behavior for a binary stream (because of possible trailing `null` characters) or for any stream with state-dependent encoding that does not assuredly end in the initial shift state.

So I guess it's the presence of null characters that lead to this behavior, though I'm not sure why they're treated differently here.